# Mapping volumes to include subfolders in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to map the logs directory for a nginx container so I don't have to keep connecting to it when i have an error, the volume mapping is half working in that I can access the files in the root of the path I am mapping too, but it is not pulling any subfolders

Docker-compose.yml config
[image: Composer Config]

and this is the contents of the source folder with in the running container

[image: Source folder contents]

which has two subfolders:
    1. Supervisor
    2. nginx

which both have files in them,

Do I have to create volume mappings for each of the subfolders as well? or is there away to specify that the mapping should include all sub folders?

Thanks

UPDATED:

here are the mounts as listed in the docker inspect. There is loads so let me know if you want to see anything else

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/home/ubuntu/dockervel/sites",
            "Destination": "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Source": "/home/ubuntu/dockervel/logs",
            "Destination": "/var/log",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Source": "/home/ubuntu/dockervel/www",
            "Destination": "/var/www",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

Docker version is Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd

Comment: This is rather odd because volume mapping includes subfolders by default (just verified on my machine). Could you post your docker version information, as well as the result of `docker inspect container_name`?

Comment: added to main post

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  I just hit this on Windows docker, for a Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml that works fine on a Mac.  Mapping a volume with two sub-dirs and a file, and only the first sub-dir appears in the container.

Comment: No. I gave up on it.  I have not needed to revisit this since.  Sorry.

Comment: Oh well, thanks.  I also just noticed that in the one subfolder that it did include, only the first of three sub-subfolders is present.  Argh.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare in dockerfile the volumes you will use.
try to extend dydx image and add the volumes you need.
Then change the .yml file to point to your image